# monotone convergence question

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int^{n^2}_{0}{e^{-x^2}n \sin\frac{x}{n}dx} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

I have tried by using the monotone convergence theorem, but if I take 
$f_n = e^{-x^2}n \sin\frac{x}{n}$ on $(0,n^2)$ and $0$ otherwise I can show neither of

1) $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ a.e

2) $\sup_n \int f_n <\infty$

Is this the right approach or am I missing something?

Comment: You won‘t be able to "switch limit with integral" here (at least not that easy), as you integral bound is depending on $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can easily prove the result using the dominated convergence theorem: let
$$f_n(x)=e^{-x^2}n\sin\left(\frac xn\right)\chi_{[0,n^2]}(x)$$
then
$$f_n(x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}xe^{-x^2}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$$
and
$$|f_n(x)|\le xe^{-x^2}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)=\varphi(x)$$
since

$$|\sin(x)|\le x,\quad \forall x\ge0$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac12e^{-x^2}\bigg|_0^\infty=\frac12$$

Comment: Wow, that was much easier than what I was trying! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Excellent, Sami! Side note: I like the OP's username! Looks very familiar to me ;-)

Comment: Wait. Why is one allowed to change $\int_0^{n^2} to \int_0^\infty$?

Comment: @keba $$\int_0^{n^2}=\int_0^\infty\chi_{[0,n^2]}$$

Comment: Cool. Thanks. :)